# How to register a new consumer in JIRA?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, oauth-1.0a

I am trying to connect to JIRA using OAuth. I have followed [this](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/api-reference/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-oauth-authentication) tutorial but when i want to create a new Application Link, it asks me to enter the URL of the application i want to link which seems strange in my case, since i want to connect a Google spreadsheet to JIRA !!!

[image: Screenshot]

I really appreciate your help Welsh, i have managed to generate a public key thanks to you and a new application link, now i want to obtain a request token from JIRA but i always get an error message when executing the request token command.

[image: Obtain Request Token]

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Just for your information: Atlassian JIRA does not yet have support for OAuth 2.0; There is a request for Atlassian at https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-43171

Answer (score 1):

The document states:

> When creating the Application Link use a placeholder URL or the correct URL to your client, if your client can be reached via HTTP and choose the Generic Application type.

So you can either use the URL to the Google Docs Spreadsheet that will be using the token to authenticate or you can just use a placeholder URL.

Comment: Ok but then JIRA asks for a Public Key, how can i get that key in my case ?

Comment: If you checkout the tutorial linked off the guide you posted it states you need to generate this yourself: https://bitbucket.org/atlassian_tutorial/atlassian-oauth-examples